# How does 'function1(data, function2)' work?

Tags: javascript

How does these code work ?

```
function output(a) {
  console.log( "The function filter return " + a + "!");
}

x = function(data, fun) {
  a = data;
  fun(a);
};

theInput = " TEXT FROM INPUT ";

x(theInput, output);//The function filter return  TEXT FROM INPUT !
```

I wrote it by mysels , and it works fine . But I don't understand how 'function1(data, function2)' run .

Comment: Read about JavaScript closures.

Comment: Nothing about closures here, the function `output` is passed to the `x` and that function is called from `x`, Read **1.** Function expressions **2.** Function: First class object **3.** Callback functions

Comment: Jepp, nothing about closures here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is `x`?

It is a variable that holds a reference to a function with two parameters, `data` and `fun`.

> Whats are you doing here?

```
x(theInput, output);
```

You call this function passing a string and a function. Yes, functions in JavaScript can be treated as any other object. Actually, they are also objects. So they can be stored to variables (store a reference to them), they can be passed as arguments to another function etc.

> What is happening inside the body of the function that is stored in x ?

Initially, you assign the `data` to the variable called `a` and then you pass this as an argument to the function `output`. Then the function that is stored in `output` is called.

If there is one takeaway from this code snippet is the fact that you passed a function as an argument to another function. This is very important in JavaScript and it is associated with the nature of functions in JavaScript.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions):

> In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects, i.e. they are
>   objects and can be manipulated and passed around just like any other
>   object. Specifically, they are Function objects.